# Set tab indicator in XML

Tags: android, xml, user-interface, tabs

Is it possible to set tab's indicator not in code behind (by using `setIndicator`), but in XML?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, sorry, you can only define tabs (whether `TabHost` or the action bar) in Java.

Answer (score 0):

No, AFAIK there is no way to set in layout xml. If you want those values dynamic, you may add them in separate xml and parse in program and set.

Answer (score 0):

no,It is not possible
But still check it out[Tabs tutorial](http://ondrejcermak.info/en/programovani/custom-tabs-in-android-tutorial/)